# Speed up 180M+ rows returned by simple SELECT with PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, performance, postgresql-9.6, google-cloud-sql, query-performance

I have performance issues on a SELECT statement which returns 180+ out of 220+ of millions of rows on my managed PostgreSQL. The table structure is the following:

```
CREATE TABLE members (
    id bigserial NOT NULL,
    customer varchar(64) NOT NULL,
    community varchar(64) NOT NULL,
    member varchar(64) NOT NULL,
    has_connected bool NULL DEFAULT false,
    CONSTRAINT members_customer_community_members_key UNIQUE (customer, community, member),
    CONSTRAINT members_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

The "guilty" SELECT query is:

```
SELECT
    community,
    member,
    has_connected
FROM
    members
WHERE
    customer = :customer;
```

I have already indexed the table:

```
CREATE INDEX members_idx ON members USING btree (customer, community, has_connected, member);
```

and the query behave well for most of the `customer` value. However, I have a customer, let's call it `1234`, which represents 80 % of the table, so the query planner prefers to scan the whole table according to the following ̀explain analyze` result:

```
Seq Scan on public.members  (cost=0.00..5674710.80 rows=202271234 width=55) (actual time=0.018..165612.655 rows=202279274 loops=1)
  Output: community, member, has_connected
  Filter: ((members.customer)::text = '1234'::text)
  Rows Removed by Filter: 5676072
Planning time: 0.106 ms
Execution time: 175174.714 ms
```

As I said earlier, my PostgreSQL is a managed instance of PostgreSQL 9.6.14 hosted on Google Cloud Platform with 10 vCPUs and 30 GB RAM. I am rather limited to the [available flags](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/flags#list-flags-postgres) , so the only PostgreSQL options tuned on this instance are:

```
max_connections: 1000
work_mem: 131072 KB
maintenance_work_mem: 2000000 KB
```

What are my options to solve this issue and to strongly reduce the query time, preferably below 30 seconds if possible ?

Comment: The only way to make this faster is to get faster hardware. Can you please show us the execution plan generated using `explain (analyze, buffers, timing) ...`?  What is your exact Postgres version? `select version();` will tell you.

Comment: So it is `PostgreSQL 9.6.14`. I will update my question with this information

Comment: Please run `set track_io_timing = on;` before generating the execution plan.

Comment: I tried but I am not allowed to do so and I have no access to the `postgres` user

Comment: Then do it without changing `track_io_timing`

Comment: I am a bit surprised that Postgres doesn't choose a Parallel Seq Scan for this table size. That would probably improve the performance.

Comment: I was surprised also, as when I tried to do a SELECT SUM(id), it managed to use a parallel seq scan. Could it be related to a more recent version of PostgreSQL ? I also tried to enable `force_parallel_mode` but it dit not improve the situation.

Comment: You're getting good help with your query but I have a related, if somewhat tangential point. I would **strongly** recommend that you **not** use an SQL keyword (`group`) as a variable name. It's confusing, leads to error prone code and won't port well. p.s. welcome to the forum! :-)

Comment: Thank you for the recommandation @Vérace ! I just replaced the name of the column in my real table as it could be slighlty business sensitive. I will update my question with a not-reserved SQL keyword.

Comment: And a big +1 for you so! :-) Seriously though, it was merited in its own right (esp. for a first question) not just for following my own sage advice!

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name The default setting of parallel_tuple_cost will keep it from using the parallel seq scan.  Nearly every tuple needs to get shoved up from the worker to the leader, and that has a cost.  If the vast majority of rows were getting filtered out in the workers, it would be different.

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned you are trying to get 80% of the rows of your table and it is normal that postgreSQL optimizer decide to scan the table rather than get data from the index. Unfortunately postgres [does not support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/309786/how-do-i-force-postgres-to-use-a-particular-index) queries with index hints like MS SQL server, so it is not possible to compare the results of index scan vs sequential scan but I am absolutely sure that you will not get better results with index scan.

Another question is why you need 180mln rows? What do you want to do with this data?
I assume that this is an analytical query so you can try some column store technologies.
Postgres have [cstore_fwd](https://www.citusdata.com/blog/2014/04/03/columnar-store-for-analytics/) extension available so you can try it out.

Comment: Indeed, it is an analytical query to compute a couple of KPIs. I am not sure that I will be allowed to use cstore_fwd as it is a managed instance but I will give it a try at least.